# Adding javascript programmatically to dynamicly generated hyperlinks with the same id

Tags: javascript

Might be a strange setup, but I have a number of hyperlinks on the page with the same id (yeah, I know, but it was not my choice and I cannot change that at this time plus those hyperlinks are generated dynamically).

Example:

```
<div id="Links">
    <div class="myItem"><a href="#" id="myLink" LinkID="101">Some text</a></div>
    <div class="myItem"><a href="#" id="myLink" LinkID="102">More text</a></div>
    <div class="myItem"><a href="#" id="myLink" LinkID="103">Even more text</a></div>
</div>
```

Now I need to attach javascript to those links dynamically (the hyperlinks are also dynamically generated). The easiest way I see is by getting all hyperlinks on the page and then check the hyperlink id to ensure I only take care of those that have id of "myLink" (I have many other hyperlinks on the page).
I thought of using getElementById but that would only grab the first element with the specified id.

am attaching javascript to those links using the following:

```
 window.onload = function() {
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];

    if (anchor.id='myLink')
    {
        if (anchor.getAttribute("LinkID") != null)
        {

            anchor.onclick = function() {           
                MyFunction(this.getAttribute("LinkID"), false);
                return false;   
            }
         }
    }
  }
}
```

The above function works fine, but it creates another issue - affects the styling of other hyperlinks on the page. So I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish the same thing but without affecting other elements on the page?

Comment: comparison is done `anchor.id==='myLink'`

Comment: so equals would be ===? not ==?   and what about "not eqauls", is it still "!="?

Comment: that is `!==` this is done to make strict comparison to avoid JS type coercion issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more modern and corrects your equality test:

```
window.onload = function() {
     var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

     for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {

       if (anchor[i].id==='myLink' && anchor[i].getAttribute("LinkID") !== null)
       {
           anchor[i].addEventListener("click", function() {           
                 MyFunction(this.getAttribute("LinkID"), false);   
           }
       }
     }
 }
```

Even with your original code, I don't see anything that would interfere with styling in the code. Can you elaborate as what styling changes you were getting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute selector and `document.querySelector([id=<id>])` pretty reliably depending on your browser support situation: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwLdKj

Then, of course, loop through that result and make subsequent changes or event bindings.

If not, you could use jQuery (referenced in above code pen).

You might also use JavaScript event delegation and listen for all click events, check if the user is clicking a link with the correct id.

Answer (score 0):

If a combination of `tag == 'a'`, `class == "myItem"` and presence of a `LinkID` attribute is sufficient to identify nodes requiring a click handler they could be identified using multiple CSS selectors. If this is not possible however, a query selector *not* using id can create a list of nodes to be checked for id, as for example:

```
function callMyFunction()
{   MyFunction(this.getAttribute("LinkID"), false);
}
function addClickHandlers()
{   var list = document.querySelectorAll("a[LinkID]")
    var i, node;
    for( i = 0; i < list.length; ++i)
    {   node = list[i];
        if(node.id == "myLink")
        {  node.onclick=callMyFunction;
        }
    }
}
```

See also running a selector query on [descendant elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) of given node if of interest.